# MVC Prevent Base Class Controller Actions being routed to

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

For a couple of my controllers I have a base class which implements the common actions.

e.g.
- BaseAccountController has a login action
- PublicAccountController inherits from BaseAccountController and implements further actions
- CorporateAccountController inherits from BaseAccountController and implements further actions

This gives the following routes:
 - BaseAccount/Login
 - PublicAccount/Login
 - CorporateAccount/Login

What is the standard way to remove the route BaseAccount/Login as this is not desired. I'm hoping for an attribute on the controller :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the following custom attribute for your Base controllers:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = false)]
public class ClosedAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
   {
       filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);
   }
}
```

You'll receive 404 for your Base controllers routes - BaseAccount/Login. But please be sure that Inherited property is false (as in example).

Example of using:

```
[Closed]
public class BaseAccountController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

you can read more (if needed) about custom action filters here - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: This Closed attribute only works on classes.. I have similar requirement. Except my base controller has many other actions as well.. I want to stop access to Action "A" directly but inherited controllers can access it through their url.. I have tried your approach but am told AttributeUsage is only for classes

Answer (score 1):

If the `BaseAccountController` has only login action then you can mark it as `abstract`.

Comment: Doesn't that mean I then have to implement it in all derived controllers?

Comment: Implement what? you mean login action? don't need! you can have a virtual impl.

Comment: I'm not following sorry, from MSDN "Members marked as abstract, or included in an abstract class, must be implemented by classes that derive from the abstract class." Which isn't what I want to do.

Comment: I think he meant marking the class as abstract, not the action. From MSDN: "An abstract class *may* contain abstract methods and accessors." You can still include a default implementation of methods, the abstract modifier just prevents the base class from being instantiated.